# Android - Proguard duplicate zip entry error - Android Support Library

Tags: android, gradle, proguard, obfuscation

I am trying to use **Proguard** in an **android application** which uses **android library projects**.
 My core android project depends on two android library projects. The core and the library projects have dependencies on **android support library** (in my case: android-support-v4.jar).
 When I try to obfuscate it with ProGuard, then I always get the following error (If the Proguarg is disabled in the Gradle script, then the compilation works fine.):

```
:MYANDROIDPROJECT:proguardDemoRelease FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':MYANDROIDPROJECT:proguardDemoRelease'.
> java.io.IOException: Can't write [MYANDROIDPROJECT_PATH\build\intermediates\classes-proguard\demo\release\classes.jar] (Can't read [MYANDROIDPROJECT_PATH\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.android.support\support-v4\21.0.3\classes.jar(;;;;;;!META-INF/MANIFEST.MF)] (Duplicate zip entry [classes.jar:android/support/v4/graphics/drawable/DrawableCompat$HoneycombDrawableImpl.class]))
```

The Gradle build script for my core project:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.12.2+'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'android'

android {
    buildToolsVersion "19.1.0"
    compileSdkVersion 19

    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
    }

    signingConfigs {
        localks {
            storeFile file("keystore/keystore")
            storePassword "xx"
            keyAlias "xx"
            keyPassword "xx"
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        debug {
            debuggable true
            runProguard false       
            zipAlign true
            signingConfig signingConfigs.localks
        }

        release {
            debuggable false   
            zipAlign true
            proguardFile 'proguard.txt'
            runProguard true        
            signingConfig signingConfigs.localks
        }
    }

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 19
        ndk{
            moduleName "S3DClient"
            abiFilter "armeabi-v7a"
            stl "gnustl_static"
        }
    }

    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'src/main/AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src/main/java']
            resources.srcDirs = ['src/main/java']
            aidl.srcDirs = ['src/main/java']
            renderscript.srcDirs = ['src/main/java']
            res.srcDirs = ['src/main/res']
            assets.srcDirs = ['src/main/assets']
            jni.srcDirs = []
        }
        paid {
            manifest.srcFile 'src/paid/AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src/paid/java']
            res.srcDirs = ['src/paid/res']

            jni.srcDirs = []
        }
        demo {
            manifest.srcFile 'src/demo/AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src/demo/java']
            res.srcDirs = ['src/demo/res']

            jni.srcDirs = []
        }
    }

    productFlavors {
        paid {
            applicationId = "hu.myprojectpackage1"
        }
        demo {
            applicationId = "hu.myprojectpackage2"
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile files('src/main/libs/sqliteassethelper-2.0.1.jar',
                  'src/main/libs/S3DXAndroidTools.jar',
                  'src/main/libs/roboguice-2.0.jar',
                  'src/main/libs/open-javageom.jar',
                  'src/main/libs/openawt.geom.jar',
                  'src/main/libs/libGoogleAnalyticsServices.jar',
                  'src/main/libs/javax.inject-1.jar',
                  'src/main/libs/guice-3.0-no_aop.jar',
                  'src/main/libs/commons-lang3-3.1.jar',
                  'src/main/libs/bugsense-3.6.jar')
    compile fileTree(dir: "$buildDir/native-libs", include: '*.jar')

    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:21.0.+'

    compile project(":lib/SlidingLayer")

    compile project(':lib/BlutoothCommunicationHandler') 
    paidCompile project(':lib/Licencing')
}
```

The Gradle build script for one of the library projects:

```
apply plugin: 'android-library'

buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.12.2+'
    }
}
dependencies {
   compile "com.android.support:support-v4:19.0.+"
}

android {
    buildToolsVersion "19.1.0"
    compileSdkVersion 19

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 4
        targetSdkVersion 18
    }
    dexOptions {
        preDexLibraries = false
    }

    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
    }

    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src']
            resources.srcDirs = ['src']
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
        }
    }
}
```

The (relevant part of) ProGuard config is:

```
-libraryjars src/main/libs/android-support-v4.jar

-keep class android.** { *; }
-keep class android.support** { *; }

-dontnote
-repackageclasses ''
-allowaccessmodification
-optimizations !code/simplification/arithmetic
-keepattributes *Annotation*

-dontwarn org.openawt.**
-dontwarn android.support.**

-optimizationpasses 5
-dontusemixedcaseclassnames
-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclasses
-dontpreverify
-verbose

-assumenosideeffects class android.util.Log {
    public static *** e(...);
    public static *** w(...);
    public static *** wtf(...);
    public static *** d(...);
    public static *** v(...);
}
-keepattributes Signature
-keepattributes *Annotation*
```

Comment: If you are going to use `Gradle`, change those dependencies to maven depdencies. Then use `android.packagingOptions` to exclude the files causing issues.

Comment: Thanks for the quick commet. Can please you describe it more deeply, how to implement it in this case?

Comment: What is the status on this?

Answer (score 7):

### Main Project `build.gradle`:

Take some time to convert these local jars:

```
dependencies {
    compile files('src/main/libs/sqliteassethelper-2.0.1.jar',
                  'src/main/libs/S3DXAndroidTools.jar',
                  'src/main/libs/roboguice-2.0.jar',
                  'src/main/libs/open-javageom.jar',
                  'src/main/libs/openawt.geom.jar',
                  'src/main/libs/libGoogleAnalyticsServices.jar',
                  'src/main/libs/javax.inject-1.jar',
                  'src/main/libs/guice-3.0-no_aop.jar',
                  'src/main/libs/commons-lang3-3.1.jar',
                  'src/main/libs/bugsense-3.6.jar')
    compile fileTree(dir: "$buildDir/native-libs", include: '*.jar')

    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:21.0.+'

    compile project(":lib/SlidingLayer")

    compile project(':lib/BlutoothCommunicationHandler') 
    paidCompile project(':lib/Licencing')
}
```

To Maven Dependencies that can be managed easily(I tried to find most of them for you!):

```
dependencies {
    // compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar') // all others
    compile 'com.readystatesoftware.sqliteasset:sqliteassethelper:2.0.1'
    compile file('src/main/libs/S3DXAndroidTools.jar')
    compile 'org.roboguice:roboguice:2.0' // latest is 3.0.1
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.1.71' // latest is 6.8.57 (issues)
    compile 'org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.3.2'
    compile 'com.bugsense.trace:bugsense:3.6'
    compile fileTree(dir: "$buildDir/native-libs", include: '*.jar')
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:21.0.3'
    compile project(":lib/SlidingLayer")
    compile project(':lib/BlutoothCommunicationHandler') 
    paidCompile project(':lib/Licencing')
}
```

After that, you should be able to use `android.packagingOptions`:

```
    packagingOptions {
        exclude '.readme'
        exclude 'LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LGPL2.1'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/README.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/dependencies.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/services/javax.annotation.processing.Processor'
    }
```

### Library Project `build.gradle`

Your library project needs to be changed from:

```
dependencies {
   compile "com.android.support:support-v4:19.0.+"
}
```

to:

```
dependencies {
   compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:21.0.3'
}
```

Your main issue was that you had two different `com.android.support:support-v4`, one in your library project and one in your main project.

Comment: Thanks. I modified my code based on your suggestion, but the error still the same (duplicate zip entry), do you have any other idea?

Comment: @BertZ You need to add that "entry" to the `packagingOptions`.

Comment: I added the following code into the gradle script, it contains that entry, but it has no effect on the duplicate zip enty error:

Comment: I tried your last suggestion as well, thanks. I really appreciate your support, but the error still the same.

Comment: @BertZ i have same error. have you fixed it? thanks.